# Biometric prompt not displayed on Android 6

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt

I am trying to use BiometricPrompt to use fingerprint sensor for authentication. My minimum supported sdk is 23 (Android M).

**It works on all android version I tested except for marshmallow.**

In marshmallow when I try to use authenticate method on button click it calls `onAuthenticationError` method from `BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback` and it gives error code `ERROR_HW_NOT_PRESENT` and error messsage:

> This device does not have a fingerprint sensor

even when device have fingerprint sensor and it also has one or more fingerprint added to it.

I have added permission/feature in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I am using jetpack library for above this.

> implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha04'

[image]

Comment: It is possible that this device does not support `FingerprintManager`, as that was brand new to the Android SDK in 6.0. You might try a test app that uses `FingerprintManager` directly and see what happens.

Comment: @CommonsWare I found that BiometricPrompt uses `PackageManager` to check if device has fingerprint sensor or not, but even if my Android 6 device has fingerprint sensor, `PackageManager` is not able to detect it and informs that fingerprint sensor not detected, but in same device `FingerprintManager` is able to detect fingerprint sensor.

Comment: You might want to file a bug report to get this improved in the AndroidX biometrics library. Be sure to mention the specific device manufacturer and model that is giving you this behavior.

Comment: Same Issue faced on my Redmi Note 3 device which having OS version 6.0.1 But I used this version lib   "implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0"  so it shows me Authentication dialog.

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved in [beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric), this bug to be exact:

```
Fixed inconsistent behavior on API Levels 23 to 27. (b/124066957)
```

Comment: it is not working ,  I used this version lib `implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0" ` 
Same Issue faced on my samsung Note 4 OS version 6.0.1